# Bash how to enter output to an array

Tags: arrays, bash, output

I have a scrip that takes input(domain) and output the domain DNS, now I want to enter this output to differentness variables, how can I do that?

```
read -p "Enter a vaild Domain ex:google.com"\  domain
echo 
if grep -qE '^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$' <<< "$do$
 then
  dns=$(host -t ns "$domain" |cut -d " " -f 4); 
 else 
        echo 'Please enter a vaild domain';exit 

fi
```

E: Also is there a way to enter input in a new line? instead in the same one.

Comment: You can enter input in a new line with `ANSI-C Quoting`, which is `$'string'`. For example, `read -p $'Enter a valid Domain ex:google.com\n' domain`.

Comment: E: This is working, thank you :) !!!

Comment: It works on my platform.

Comment: `echo "Enter a vaild Domain ex:google.com"; read domain`

Answer (score 0):

With `ANSI-C Quoting`, whose form is `$'string'`, you can implement entering input on a new line. For example:

```
read -p $'Enter a valid Domain ex:google.com\n' domain
```

Refer to [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)